# Combine list components to a vector

Tags: r, list

Suppose, I have a list:

```
l = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"))

[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "e" "f"
```

I want to get a vector.

```
"ad" "be" "cf"
```

I can convert the list to a matrix, e.g.,`sapply(l, c)`, and then concatenate columns, but, perhaps, there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `paste0`

```
Reduce(paste0, l)
[1] "ad" "be" "cf"
```

Or with `do.call`

```
do.call(paste0, l)
[1] "ad" "be" "cf"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option

```
> apply(list2DF(l), 1, paste0, collapse = "")
[1] "ad" "be" "cf"
```